# Use any unicode character in source with pdfLaTeX (without XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX)

Tags: symbols, unicode, input-encodings, font-encodings, utf8

I'm writing a script that converts .md files into latex source code and compiles it to a .pdf. I've been using pdfLaTeX and would rather not refactor this late in the game. I want to be able to handle any unicode character that might come up in the .md file. From other posts here, I've gotten this somewhat exhaustive solution, but there are still a few characters that break it (like the last one U+FFFD)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
% \usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

¡ | ¢ | £ | ¤ | ¥ | ¦ | § | ¨ | © | ª | « | ¬ | ­ | ® | ¯
° | ± | ² | ³ | ´ | µ | ¶ | · | ¸ | ¹ | º | » | ¼ | ½ | ¾ | ¿
À | Á | Â | Ã | Ä | Å | Æ | Ç | È | É | Ê | Ë | Ì | Í | Î | Ï
Ð | Ñ | Ò | Ó | Ô | Õ | Ö | × | Ø | Ù | Ú | Û | Ü | Ý | Þ | ß
à | á | â | ã | ä | å | æ | ç | è | é | ê | ë | ì | í | î | ï
ð | ñ | ò | ó | ô | õ | ö | ÷ | ø | ù | ú | û | ü | ý | þ ����

\end{document}
```

Comment: well only you know which chars can come up in your files. Add a definition for every missing one with \DeclareUnicodeChar.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Is your problem how to get a unicode character from your .md file into your .tex file, or how to properly handle the .tex file that results?

Comment: Maybe you know it, but pandoc https://pandoc.org/ is quite good at it...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I considered that, but I'm trying to get this to work for any future .md file, so going through all the possible unicode characters would be impractical.

Comment: @Teepeemm I'm able to generate a .tex file, I just can't figure out how to get the .tex file to recognize any unicode character

Comment: @Rmano I'll take another look at pandoc. I had started with it originally but a few blogs recommended pdfLaTeX so I switched.

Comment: There are (according to wikipedia) currently 143,859  names chars in unicode. Do you want premade definitions for all of them?

Comment: Ideally I'd want a package that lets pdfLaTeX render all of them. It seems like `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` do this to an extend, but aren't complete.

Comment: An encoding like T1 can support 256 character, you would need more than 500 encodings (and related fonts) to support all unicode.

Comment: No one one is ever going to make the effort to put together hundreds of fonts to cover the current unicode range and all the tex code to map the different ranges to different fonts, just to get the effect of a single font style, when you can use xelatex or lualatex and get access to all the "unicode" open type fonts on your system and even they typically don't cover the full range.

Comment: Whoever recommended that you use pdfLaTeX and steered you away from LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX did you a terrible disservice.

Comment: You are specifying `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` that is you are stating that you are using the T1 encoding so  256 characters covering just Latin scripts as used in Western Europe. That is completely incompatible with asking for full Unicode coverage.

Comment: Why not XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX?  They work with the same tex commands; the only difference is that you'll have a simpler preamble.

Comment: Pandoc is not "instead of" pdflatex...what pandoc does to convert markdown to PDF is to create a latex source that you can compile (and if you have lot of unicode, compile with xe- or lua- and be happy).