# How to make my non-latin pdflatex document more copy-paste friendly?

Tags: pdftex, font-encodings, characters, alphabet, ascii

I write and typeset articles in languages that do not use the latin alphabet using pdflatex. I have received requests from foreigners to make it easier to run the document in Google Translator. According to them when they open my pdfs in a viewer and select certain parts then copy paste, the text is completely unreadable. Indeed when I tried copy pasting a few sentences to notepad I got strings filled with `àáâãäåæçèéêëìíîï` and other unreadable text.

After doing research I learned that in LaTeX all fonts use code range `00-FF` so all non-latin scripts when copied will contain codes that do not correspond to their unicode values. Is there any package or trick that automatically maps non-ascii letters to unicode? I would like to make non-English articles more accessible to a wider audience and remove the technical barrier. Non-XeTeX solutions especially welcome.

Comment: Please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means. -- by default with most packages the copied text should still be "mostly readable" so it depends on which package you use.

Comment: Possible reason [pdf - How can I make the copied-pasted text from an pdflatex output still readable/compilable by pdflatex? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175600/how-can-i-make-the-copied-pasted-text-from-an-pdflatex-output-still-readable-com)

Comment: xelatex and lualatex can use unicode fonts. pdflatex is limited to 256-character font files - if you have to use pdflatex, you can create hundreds of font files (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/578636/use-any-unicode-character-in-source-with-pdflatex-without-xelatex-or-lualatex), but xelatex or lualatex is much much simpler.

Comment: you should provide a small example, and say which latex release you have current releases include a unicode map for most pdftex encodings. Unicode support is of course far easier on luatex or xetex